How to decode a set of values encoded in an unknown encoding
I'm trying to decode a value that is unknown for me. My first though it was gzip because I can see these headers:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmsg"; filename="message"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
but none of gzip decoding tools can handle that.
Here's what I know:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cmsg"; filename="message"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
"message"\x0d\x0aContent-Type: application/octet-stream\x0d\x0aContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a\x1f\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00í\ûS\x1b9\x12þW®tuùÉf%ÍKãº\\x15Áf×ÙØìòHBXJ%ÏÈFñ<Ì< \x0eÇÿ~-Í\x18l\x13%©gFên}_·¦[#ç\x0a\x15*¨E<B-x}»ÄdÂUZ:.ÆÔ²=Ï¶|f¡êÖÌàíÐ-\x0c\x1c¼E°\x0f·\x06¥B1j9Ìv\êû¤4ÉeRð¼\x10\x05h²\x1a(\x17*è ×üÕwð.ôMóZª\x16T5¨,\x18Pì\x0d\x06Ämº¦Mð°9ð±h\x06a)±¨ï1è2\x14±¦ü;zæ2ÏUT}v\x0fxH\x02B=Ù´\x02æ6± aÓ\x1a`Ú¤Ä¥ôå\x04ÃæpÔ¤¦ó9jQÚ@¥éN0Æbf¹Ì²\x1d\x0c\x0dH¨8G­\x13t\x16`k{ßJö»Eà\x1e_\x1dî¼V\x05õ>Èþû#:\x1a_ª\x12xóGòû8\x19ì¾«¶};ü\x1d\x02\x1a¢\x10 à\x0aÉOE\x06®ÐD$XÉ\f\x172äc9½L³ÇiXF\x1aØ\x18Æ$Ì¸J\x06é'"'"'.Â\x1cl \x16n \x04ØÆÀq&Bòb:Ñ\x1d.ÕP54ºÙ=Ò3y^Ê¼+\x110\x04SÔj-|Ý@Q:\x09\x0a"¥É\x17pÔ.1kC\x11åZpíj[s¾F;>X$ôudL¥ü"Ó¸x\x12©dÄ3ã4àF\x18\x01Ìb>vÜëÆ<\x1aY\x1a§ÅB\x10ê»Å\x1c\x0f\x13Û±\x1cUÈÉ­e¡\x1cªDæ\x17"R\x00nqðÑ¢2XFj¤\x06*RÅT#PF\x05týCä\x1a¿5@9ÀÎ'"'"'|ÞÜKÐAÏèøyßß$Í\x0b~\x17Äg\x04ÝÓa734\x11\x08dlû:`F\x03¯Bÿ\x0aÄ¬8^I\x1aõT\x14©\O7®G°ë[¾\x0fóî_h\x04\x08Ø\x1e±`^ÂÕ¤mÑíºÉÝ3¬0ºÞ°V\x19Z\x14ÑÈöÝä\x06TæÚ\x18?\x0cyxÉ"8»·!³}FmLÌ2*ÄJ\x02¹«»Ìémz><©O6DÎ\x0cÍKÐ\x01Ù\x01&¦\x0f¢4(³¬¦îëÄE"/Ú*Uh±©¾][°¦Q;½¼%Ë¹HXõmkZ`¶^qIN\x11¦Õ·\x1e?lªxUIßNZ&EÍÍíÕ7F"à®\x11ÍT,²é¶Ñ5ß|áÆ|\Â#1üb¥[·½6Ö\x0eU\x04jòûèÜ\x15*ºCgÕ§\x0fVë`éu\x0e\x0e:ý_;ûüð·ýÎvw\x0føÎ^¯wÔï\x1e\x1eóß¶\x0f×\x06mëñÑ6ªgæ\x14g\x14!¿uì\x1bËfwf5\x0bu\x09&C,[{0ÈJòIÝ\x08êuu|ä<(ÔTifP7bêV{ý\x0e?ÜãðIElÊ'"'"'©2Î_SqpÔëmï\x1f¯K>èÌá¯+&1¼\x1e\x11?ÔÕ¿UU\x15ÆÒLCaÂÙ¶eSÛ%®C)kÝ¥cbÔfUõVVge¤Çvõ\x17*ÿó%\x19×Ð©L²¹Á\x0f4\x09ý@GI\x13x\x00é\x01\x1a3LÒ1³P£5^ tÙªÖÝB·Ô*¨«W\x08\x12ci1\x10\x17½\x04hæEÊ+¶ób!b»ýW{ï5>Á±iM\x02õ\x0bE*\x08\x08Æ\x0f¬SAÿH7­y·Alµ Äê\x12¡Õ2\x1cªß³®`îÕ£¡ë\x11PÍæ\x03*©Lêòp¨F\~ò±Ì$\x07áßÍ£\x0b°Á\x0c"³DD|©\x1359 \x1c\x15ðàzÂ\x1c\x08 f6AMD&bOd\x00å%Ëµ ¶\x1c\x07[\x1eó\x1db\x16q\x0aQ:*\x0e:ûo;ûÕÛÙï&s×\x0b\x06¥¬½\x1aÔ¹¶ÆÌ¡_\x0bM\x1ej\x15Y)ÍÂ\x1eº&Ð\x01gpfæè\x0b\x14\x0céÃX?ëuàÏ¹?=è\x12A óÎ\x0b/|Çñ\x1d1¹P °÷\x0e·/{íÑ\x14~?÷?Âoûèò?ÇÏÏý½\x0aïÿ\x16·moV·!vÏmuÙÖ¤\x16kÀÚ\x0f]ÝÒÈ?Þê\x16s\x1c¶!ò¬nUÄ­xuk\x13Õ­Urê<5§?Ñê\x16³Ý§FûY'"'"'Ã.]¨Æ6ÉðsÁî%Ã·\x1eSÆ:°ö#aüã%Ã.±í\x0d?"\x19®[m2¼ËM2¼RNý§æôçIWöP¢ÌêVæ\x15ÛíKÅ»¯tÕÐ\x12\x06\x1eôfïÚ¼\x0d\x19é\x17.N^ï5ÊBì\x06Á0ð2§iÃ×\x14¶+>8@\x18:®ãZ&VLÊ§ÆÍ¼-1\x12ëáÀ8'"'"'\%õëW´ôþ8)£h=dóï\x02£(à3PÒL6\x05Í=Ø¹Äzºðy×3O\x0aÝó*g\x00*Ç_I\x1dHûÕL\x05üãU3\x04ÛtÃãê\x19o+-f6Q¹©eVJéï,ÿij\x15¡ýl?HãX$áìtµ\x15N:\x1c©³Ý³½J\x1eaúÄ%6±<8±|w=(ðïl\Õ&×ñ|\x0aÚbW¢¾«¤¤xÕ?§º\x0f\x1cÀ²\x1eµîí6\x06¯´Ìô×aÂ`\x09õ~Û²¿°iÚ\x0cãïm]Ä\x10´ì,\x0dD©ù0µPëÄÂ§\x0dD¨\x11C\x1cPy\x1b\x16u\x18\x1cl½åxfË11GjVµ¼`öÃk\x07 s¦\x11h ÿf(ç*çêñ×[7\x0962\x1e\x03püÿá½°\x11Aáë\x083wiÿ Fø\x04~ Ce¢ÓèG\x0ej ÝW¯²t,³¢c7ì-Çõ\x1a\x04®]®:ÀÍ\x07N\x1b'"'"'N\x00\x11'"'"'à;>ó\x1a¾ïoùpj°2¦ÂO\x03Ñ(#³º³25îií\x12'"'"'´\x010Á\x09®ÜÃ\x1c5ù[ÄÐ_Q9ï\x01zZ³_+ÕÚ«¿}×\x18\x04.µdöyk\x1f]]ÍèzDí\x17Qü7¼èT\x0b2{¦c\x15d)\x1f\x08¨ÓL6¨KË;*§U\x04"ËªNÉ/\x02=Ð\x09¼ëîvÑÍèàL\x06ã\ÿ7\x01è<ÿoðRN__v?¦êøó¾ú\x10¿U½\x1dz\x1c÷¬þá¸÷ydïµ»ÓãøÏÏýÃ×ñÞ;¸Þ>Vov^Ò}Â!ëÅÇ\x16¤N¤÷qD÷ÚÛúhï]ÇéÑ·Qï×}|ø6Þkûïºjøç¿¬6ü}Qä/«Ô!\x0c¿8¿xyá½È_JAÍBÏó\x14.LXÌ\x1f\x0e$&Âµ\x05L~·¸|Ï,b¢\x0b\x1dçß½ã¡ëÿ\x01m(o\x03bA\x00\x00\x0d\x0a--o-5geLz_QmsILVGAAewLHqRNyZ8O8iL8pAjcSK--\x0d\x0a'

